# Obstructions to locally trivial deformations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $X$ be a complex projective variety.
If $X$ is smooth, then the first-order infinitesimal deformations are given by $H^1(X, T_X)$ and the obstructions are in $H^2(X, T_X)$.

Now assume that $X$ is singular, but we consider only *locally trivial* deformations (in the sense of [Flenner and Kosarew](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=918518)).
Then the statement about $H^1$ remains true, and so does the second one, according to [Sernesi's book](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2247603), Prop. 2.4.6.
However, unwinding the proof one finds that in fact a nonsingularity hypothesis is used, namely when applying the Infinitesimal Lifting Property.

> **Question:** Is it true that $H^2(X, T_X)$ is an obstruction space for the locally trivial deformation functor $\mathrm{Def^{lt}}(X)$?

Ideally, an answer would either indicate how to fix the proof of Prop. 2.4.6 above, or give an example of a variety $X$ with $\mathrm{Def^{lt}}(X)$ singular even though $H^2(X, T_X) = 0$.

Comment: For locally trivial deformations, you only need to specify gluing data. The relevant automorphisms are given by the tangent sheaf, and failure of the cocycle condition is a class in $H^2$. What am I missing?

Comment: First you need to extend the automorphisms themselves to one order higher, and this requires the Infinitesimal Lifting Property. E.g. for k[x,y]/(xy), the automorphism given by x \mapsto x+t modulo t^2 does not extend to an automorphism modulo t^3.

Comment: Good point.The obstruction to deforming $X$ lies in $Ext^2_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathbb{L}_X, \mathcal{O}_X)$, where $\mathbb{L}$ is the cotangent complex, and you seek an element of $H^2(X, \mathcal{Ext}^0(\mathbb{L}_X, \mathcal{O}_X))$. I can see why local triviality kills contributions to the obstruction from $\mathcal{Ext}^2$, but that doesn't rule out a contribution involving $\mathcal{Ext}^1$.